VSCode Logic App Fetching information on versions of extension bundle
When attempting to Run a Logic App in VSCode I get the error below
When I run c:\Users\xxxx\.azurelogicapps\dependencies\FuncCoreTools\func host start from a command prompt in the folder where host.json is it works
I looked at the verbose logs and I suspect it is this step that causes the problem.
[2024-05-16T12:41:46.149Z] Fetching information on versions of extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows available on https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows/index.json

Is it possible to disable this check in VSCode?
 Executing task: C:\Users\xxxx\.azurelogicapps\dependencies\FuncCoreTools\func host start 


Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2024-05-16T12:35:05.618Z] There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository.
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.621Z] Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.622Z] Status: 301 (Moved Permanently)
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.622Z] 
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.623Z] Headers:
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.624Z] Server: BlueCoat-Security-Appliance
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.624Z] Location: REDACTED
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.625Z] Connection: close
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.625Z] .
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.656Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'fe9f6d13-1e96-4772-9cea-784392c5085c'.
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.657Z] Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.658Z] Status: 301 (Moved Permanently)
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.658Z] 
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.659Z] Headers:
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.660Z] Server: BlueCoat-Security-Appliance
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.661Z] Location: REDACTED
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.661Z] Connection: close
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.662Z] .
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.853Z] There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository.
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.855Z] Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.855Z] Status: 301 (Moved Permanently)
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.861Z] 
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.862Z] Headers:
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.862Z] Server: BlueCoat-Security-Appliance
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.863Z] Location: REDACTED
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.863Z] Connection: close
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.863Z] .
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.874Z] Host startup operation has been canceled

Logic App workflow below (StackOverlfow is forcing me to add more details so here is some text)
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Send_message": {
                "type": "ServiceProvider",
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "entityName": "qu001",
                        "message": {
                            "contentData": "hello"
                        }
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "serviceBus",
                        "operationId": "sendMessage",
                        "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/serviceBus"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {}
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "type": "Recurrence",
                "recurrence": {
                    "interval": 3,
                    "frequency": "Day"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}


can you please share your logic app workflow

@IkhtesamAfrin I added the workflow to the question

If you are using service bus connector then why you are getting blob storage error?

Are you using Blob storage connector?

No not using Blob storage contanier

From the logs I can see that Bluscoat (a security product) is blocking access to something func.exe is trying to reach on the internet. This line "There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository." is the problem - I need to get the URL it is trying to reach.

It is pretty straight forward to achieve if you are correctly following my steps. I believe it is your network issue

I agree but I can't resolve the issue if i don't know what URL func is trying to access. If I knew the URL I could get an exception made on the security device.

Use When a HTTP request is received trigger instead of recurrence in logic app workflow and then use the request URL

Tried that but It is the same problem. The problem is in startup of func.exe [2024-05-16T12:35:05.618Z] There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository.
[2024-05-16T12:35:05.621Z] Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.

Try to add the func exe path in the exception list

Exceptions are URLs not exes so unfortunately that is not possible

As When a HTTP request is received doesn't work for you either, so I would suggest you to check with your security product team

I have followed below steps to send a message to service bus queue using standard logic app in vs code.

I have created a logic app workflow alike you with the below code in workflow.json file.

Please note, I choose Use connectors from Azure option while adding the connectors in designer.
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Send_message": {
                "type": "ServiceProvider",
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "entityName": "test",
                        "message": {
                            "contentData": "Hello"
                        }
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "serviceBus",
                        "operationId": "sendMessage",
                        "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/serviceBus"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {}
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "type": "Recurrence",
                "recurrence": {
                    "interval": 3,
                    "frequency": "Minute"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}

I have below code in host.json file.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}


Enabled Azurite by clicking Fn + F1 -> Azurite start.

I am able to get the expected response while debugging it.


Executing task: C:\Users\*****\.azurelogicapps\dependencies\FuncCoreTools\func host start 


Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554


Functions:

        WorkflowDispatcher: edgeWorkflowRuntimeTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-17T12:33:16.055Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-05-17T12:33:20.001Z] Executing 'Functions.WorkflowDispatcher' (Reason='(null)', Id=43196e17-f9f3-4aa7-962b-a2d269efd239)    
[2024-05-17T12:33:22.917Z] Executed 'Functions.WorkflowDispatcher' (Succeeded, Id=43196e17-f9f3-4aa7-962b-a2d269efd239, Duration=3000ms)


Service Bus -

